# Unit for Left Adjoint to the Inclusion Functor

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I have the following construction, which seems too easy. Could you review and comment? Thanks in advance.

Suppose $I$  is a set, and $P(I)$ is its power set, viewed as a category whose arrows are set inclusion. Then the functor $i:P(I)\rightarrow Set/I$ defined in the obvious way by $U(\subset I)\mapsto(U\hookrightarrow I)$ and $(U\subset V)\mapsto $ 
\begin{array}{&&} 
U & {\to} & V\\
& \searrow & \downarrow  \\ 
 & & I
\end{array}

(where all the arrows are inclusions) has a left adjoint, $F$.

$F:Set/I\rightarrow P(I)$ just takes any $h:X\rightarrow I$ to $h(X)$. On arrows $\varphi :h\rightarrow h'$, we have 
\begin{array}{&&} 
X & \stackrel{\varphi}{\to} & X' \\
& h \searrow & \downarrow h' \\ 
 & & I
\end{array}

so that $h(X)\subset h'(X')$ as required. The unit, $\eta _{h}:h\rightarrow (i\circ F)h$ is then $h \rightarrow (h(X)\hookrightarrow I)$. If $f:h\rightarrow i(V)$ then $h(X)\subset V$ and so we get our (unique) $ \overline f:Fh\rightarrow V$. To show that 
\begin{array}{&&} 
h & \stackrel{\eta _{h}}{\to} & i(Fh) \\
& f \searrow & \downarrow i(\overline f) \\ 
 & & i(V)
\end{array}

commutes just amounts to observing that $f=h$.

Comment: Dear Chilango, What is it that doesn't make sense to you?  A morphism $\varphi$ is exactly a map from $X$ to $X'$ making the diagram you wrote commute, and from the diagram we see that indeed $h(X) = h'(\varphi(X)) \subset h'(X')$, which is what we want (isn't it?).  Regards,

Comment: Of course. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Chilango, No worries, I'm glad it was as simple as that.  Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The OP essentially answered their question in the course of posing it:

By definition $h = h'\circ \varphi,$ and so $h(X) = h'(\varphi(X)) \subset h'(X')$,
as required.